# Using Weights in Weka

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka

In Weka you can set different weights to instances. 
The weight of each instance has an impact on a classifier (which takes weights into consideration). If I set the weight of an instance to 0 it means that I ignore this instance. If I set the weight to 2 for a given instance then it's like oversampling it (2 times the same instance).

My question is: what happens if I set negative values to the weight ? As I checked java does not crush (i've just used naive bayes). But what happens internally ? Is the instance ignored or something else is happening ? How does this have an impact on a classifier ? And if it has an impact, does this apply to all classifiers the same way or different classifiers behave differently ?

Comment: Each classifier in Weka is implemented separately (and not all of them even support instance weights) so the answer will depend on the classifier. All the Weka code is open source though, so if you want to know what happens internally you can have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The impact of that feature will be negative on the classification. This means that instead of contributing to the classifier in assigning a given class, it will contribute to the classifier not learning that classification. Think of using a negative weight to a value in any operation. As commented by nekomatic, each classifier will use weights differently when they use it.